# A question on Lightswitch web application

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Is it possible to create a web application in LightSwitch which can be hosted on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can host on the desktop, on a remote IIS Server or in Azure. This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2010/08/06/the-anatomy-of-a-lightswitch-application-overview.aspx) describes the LightSwitch architecture in more detail.